# Oracle APEX grid displays only date without time

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a field in the database that contains date and time - DATE type in the database. When I run the query in Toad, I can see data and time, but when I pull up the data in the APEX report, only date shows up, no time. How can I ensure the time comes up as well?

Comment: Try different date formats: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm

Comment: what different data format? In Oracle database it is `DATE`, it returns date with time. It is just not displaying correct in APEX

Comment: How are you retrieving the value in APEX? Are you using a format mask? https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6381/index-en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "Format Mask" column attribute in the Page Designer.
Go to Page Designer, find your report region, open list of columns, find your column and set "Format Mask" e.g. to yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.

Another option is to change the SQL query used for the report, make explicit conversion `to_char` for the desired column.

Comment: Thank you! just what i wanted

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: You shouldn't use `to_char` conversion inside report query, because of sorting.